# How to divide each word of a text into several different maps?

Tags: scala

I am a beginner in scala and I am looking to create a value mapping that associates to each word of the string "text" the number 1 in the form of a Map.

```
val text = """It is a period of civil wars in the galaxy. A brave alliance of underground freedom fighters has challenged the tyranny and oppression of the awesome GALACTIC EMPIRE.
Striking from a fortress hidden amoug the billion stars of the galaxy, rebel spaceships have won their first victory in a battle with the powerful Imperial Starfleet.
The EMPIRE fears that another defeat could bring a thousand more solar systems into the rebellion, and Imperial control over the galaxy would be lost forever.
To crush the rebellion once and for all, the EMPIRE is constructing a sinister new battle station. Powerful enough to destroy an entire planet, its completion spells certain doom for the champions of freedom.
"""
```

I tried this but it is not the result I am looking for:

```
val mapping = text.split("\\W+").map(_ -> 1).toMap

mapping.take(5).foreach(println)

//(sinister,1)
//(fighters,1)
//(battle,1)
//(galaxy,,1)
//(tyranny,1)
```

What I would like to get out is this:

```
val mapping = ...

mapping.take(5).foreach(println)
// Map(It -> 1)
// Map(is -> 1)
// Map(a -> 1)
// Map(period -> 1)
// Map(of -> 1)
```

How could I have a release like this?

Thanking you in advance for the help you will give me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the right answer was this:

```
val mapping = text.split("\\W+").map(word => Map(word -> 1))
```

Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 2):

`split` uses a regular expression as a separator. You can use `\\W+`, which means "one or more non-word characters" (spaces, new lines, punctuation etc.).

```
text.split("\\W+").map(_ -> 1).toMap
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
It allowed me to simplify the whole redundant part, but unfortunately I always get the same result, and not the one I would like to have.